# InvokeOperation C# and Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

Can anyone help with the following code?

I'm trying to pass value from server to client via RIA Silverlight, but keep getting `NullReferenceException`.

I have removed all other attempts that I have tried and have just posted last attempt.

#### Server-side Code

```
 namespace Web.UI.SilverlightDomainServices 
 { 
    // Implements application logic using the SilverlightDBEntities context. 
    // TODO: Add your application logic to these methods or in additional methods. 
    // TODO: Wire up authentication (Windows/ASP.NET Forms) and uncomment the following to disable anonymous access 
    // Also consider adding roles to restrict access as appropriate. 
    // [RequiresAuthentication] 
    [EnableClientAccess()] 
    public class VideoAdvertDomainService : LinqToEntitiesDomainService<SilverlightDBEntities> 
    { 
        // TODO: 
        // Consider constraining the results of your query method.  If you need additional input you can 
        // add parameters to this method or create additional query methods with different names. 
        // To support paging you will need to add ordering to the 'at_AdvertVideoAdvertisement' query. 


        string strMonthYear = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM-yyyy"); 

        [Invoke] 
        public List<string> GetMediaURLBasedOnMonthYear(string strMonthYear) 
        { 
            return (from p in this.ObjectContext.at_AdvertVideoAdvertisement 
                    where p.AdvertMediaMonthYear == strMonthYear 
                    select p.AdvertMediaURL).ToList(); 
        } 

        public IQueryable<at_AdvertVideoAdvertisement> GetAt_AdvertVideoAdvertisement() 
        { 
            return this.ObjectContext.at_AdvertVideoAdvertisement; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

#### Client-side Code

```
namespace Web.Silverlight  
{  
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl  
    {  
        public MainPage()  
        {  
            InitializeComponent();  
            Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);  
        }  

        private VideoAdvertDomainContext ctx = new VideoAdvertDomainContext();  

        private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
        {  
            string strMonthYear = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM-yyyy");  

            VideoAdvertDomainContext DomainContext = new VideoAdvertDomainContext();  
            InvokeOperation iv = DomainContext.GetMediaURLBasedOnMonthYear("September-2012");  
            iv.Value.ToString();  
            PlaylistItem item = new PlaylistItem();  
            item.MediaSource = new Uri(iv.Value.ToString());  
            item.DeliveryMethod = Microsoft.SilverlightMediaFramework.Plugins.Primitives.DeliveryMethods.AdaptiveStreaming;  
            MP.Playlist.Add(item);  

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about telling us which object is null?

Comment: Please post the stack trace from the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the stack trace from the exception, I have to guess.

## Possibility 1

It could be that `ObjectContext` is `null` and therefore, this line will throw the exception you are getting.

```
return (from p in this.ObjectContext.at_AdvertVideoAdvertisement 
        where p.AdvertMediaMonthYear == strMonthYear 
        select p.AdvertMediaURL).ToList();
```

## Possibility 2

Is there a chance that the contents of `this.ObjectContext.at_AdvertVideoAdvertisement` are `null`?

If so, `p` could be `null`, which would cause the query to throw the exception.

## Possibility 3

I suspect the offending line is:

```
iv.Value.ToString();
```

This line does nothing, but you also repeat this a couple of lines later in a useful context, so perhaps the first declaration is a mistake. However, this assumes that the `InvokeOperation` value returned by `VideoAdvertDomainContext.GetMediaURLBasedOnMonthYear` is not `null` and that its `Value` property is not `null`. This may not be the case.

## Recommendation

I recommend placing a breakpoint on those lines and seeing what the variables look like in the debugger to track down the `null` reference. From there, you can start to work out why it is `null` and either make it so that it isn't, or fix your code so that it copes appropriately with `null` references.

Comment: Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  StackTrace:
       at Web.Silverlight.MainPage.MainPage_Loaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(UInt32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
       at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName, UInt32 flags)
  InnerException:

Comment: Server side code is returning data when hits breakpoint. Just not passing data to silverlight via RIA as per null reference exception